# reinstall or uninstall .msi windows

Tags: windows-installer, espeak

somehow my version of espeak-ng is not working in my windows so i wanted to uninstall it and reinstall it. I uninstalled it from control panel and rerun the espeak-ng.msi file but it says "another version of this product already exists..." . I tried to uninstall with the .msi by left clicking it and choosing "uninstall" but the same message appears. I also tried with command like to force reinstalling it like "msiexec /i espeak-ng-x64.msi  /q REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=A " but it does not work neither... 
help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using this windows program :

https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed